unable to load grapesjs-blocks-basic in angular cli 18
we are using latest angular and nodejs version, we want to include grapesjs basic blocks and am following steps as mentioned in https://github.com/GrapesJS/blocks-basic
after installing npm i grapesjs-blocks-basic, i am not able to see the grapesjs-blocks-basic.min.js in node_modules folder

if i try using import grapesjs-blocks-basic, it is not working either. also i tried using script "node_modules/grapesjs-blocks-basic/dist/index.js", it is also not loading the controls.
what correction is required?

Angular CLI: 18.2.11
Node: 22.9.0


First install the packages:
npm i grapesjs-blocks-basic
npm i grapesjs

Then we can add the styles and scripts for grapes in the angular.json file:
      "options": {
        "assets": [],
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "browser": "src/main.ts",
        "outputPath": "dist/demo",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/grapesjs/dist/grapes.min.js",
          "node_modules/grapesjs-blocks-basic/dist/index.js"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css",
          "src/global_styles.css"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"
      }

Then go to the component, where you want to insert, instead of #gjs which can cause problems when there are multiple editors, go for #gjs (Template Reference Variable) which we can take a view child of and input the nativeElement property into the configuration.
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';
import plugin from 'grapesjs-blocks-basic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div #gjs></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('gjs') gjs!: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: this.gjs.nativeElement,
      // ...
      plugins: [plugin],
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you. i was trying to append blockManager to external nav bar. your example helped me.
